# Uplift calculation in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following data aggregation table:

```
group_name | period | sum(spend) | count(store_id)
A | pre | 100 | 5
A | current | 150 | 4
B | pre | 80 | 10
B | current | 50 | 10
```

I want to use SQL to basically transform the data into the following (where spend_per_store_id is just sum(spend)/count(store_id) and uplift is the ratio between current / pre):

```
uplift | A | B | A compared to B current | A compared to B pre
sum(spend) | current/pre | current/pre | current/current | pre/pre
spend_per_store_id | current/pre | current/pre | current/current | pre/pre
```

I am a bit stuck on how to do this without using a whole bunch of case statements and union alls.

Edit: expected output example (calculation provided rather than the actual numbers)

```
uplift | A | B | A compared to B current | A compared to B pre
sum(spend) | 150/100 | 50/80 | 150/50 | 150/80
```

Answer (score 0):

The operation of transposing rows to columns is a pivot, and there are some simple, involved or proprietary ways of doing a pivot.. but the simplest way for you, given that you seem to  only have a set of data for current and pre per group, that you want to associate together, might be to just use a join:

```
SELECT ..., cur.sumspend / pre.sumspend as percent_spend_change 
FROM

  (SELECT * FROM table WHERE period = 'pre') pre
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM table WHERE period = 'current') cur
  ON pre.group_name = cur.group_name
```

Now replace the first `SELECT ...` with calculations for everything you want to know. For example uplift is `cur.sumspend / pre.sumspend` or `cur.sumspend - pre.sumspend` (depending on how you define "uplift"/as a percentage or raw value) and so on..

Comment: The issue is you are trying to divide a pre value with a current value. So filtering on period will not achieve this.

Comment: Why not? One subquery gets all the `pre`, the other all the `cur`, the join connects the two datasets by group name. This essentially means that your 4 row (A current, A prev, B current, B prev) dataset becomes a 2 row one (A current prev, B current prev) so the pre/current for A etc are on the same row and the math can be done

Comment: In my mind your question was to compare A pre with A curr and B pre with B curr because you said *ratio between current / pre* - to ratio two items you need them on the same row, ergo I provide a query where pre and curr for A (and also likewise for B) are moved onto the same row . If I misunderstood you and you're trying to compare A pre with B pre and A curr with B curr then just swap the WHERE and the join around, so you're `WHERE group_name = 'A') a` / `WHERE group_name = 'B') b` and `JOIN ON a.period = b.period`

Comment: you also want to compare groups and periods, hence the matrix structure. Adding any kind of filter 'locks' one dimension. That is the tricky part I think?

Comment: I have to admit, I'm not really understanding what you're asking.Could you maybe take another look at your qustion and give some nicely formatted expected output? The only thing that looks like desired output is a bit of a mess..

Comment: Added an example with actual numbers :)

Comment: When you look at your own question, does it make sense? Show it to a colleague.. I'm more confused than I was before